# How to apply multiple if condition filter in djago template

Tags: django

I am rendering two filter from my views to html template. 1) notifications_approved 2)notifications_pending. I am using this two filter separately in my html. Is there any way to use this two filter together in if statement?  here is my code:

****#html template****

```
{% for notification in  notifications_approved  %} 
{% endif %}

{% for notification in notifications_pending %} 
{%endif%}
```

I tried this but it's not rendering anything's in my template:

```
{%if notification in  notifications_approved or notifications_pending %}
 {%endif%}
```

I also tried this

```
{%if notification|notifications_approved or notification|notifications_pending %}
{%endif%} #getting TemplateSyntaxError
```

I also surprised very much why this if statement **not working**:

```
{% if notification in  notifications_approved  %} 
{% endif %}
```

**views.py**

```
def ShowAuthorNOtifications(request):
    notifications_approved = Notifications.objects.filter(notification_type="Comment Approved").order_by('-date')
    notifications_pending =   Notifications.objects.filter(notification_type="New Comment").order_by('-date')
```

Comment: `{%if notification in notifications_approved or notification in notifications_pending %}`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  I did little bit mistake in my question. Currently I am using for statement. When try to using if statement or try to use two condition together in if statement my template rendering nothings

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem tried `{%if notification in notifications_approved or notification in notifications_pending %}` but not rendering anything in my template

Comment: @boyenec there is no error that I can see in the template, but without the data (or even your test data), it is impossible to say why this isn't working.

Comment: We need more details. Please provide a [mcve]. How are you rendering the template? What is the `context` that you pass when you render it?

Answer (score 1):

```
{% if notification in  notifications_approved  %} 
{% endif %}
```

If statement not working because we are not comparing anything. notifications_approved is a query set which contains list of objects. You need to loop it first. Secondly, if you need to check if the query set is empty or not, use:

```
{% with notifications_approved as np  %}
{% if np %} 
     # your code
{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

OR

```
{% if notifications_approved or notifications_pending %}
```

OR

```
{% if notifications_approved.exists or notifications_pending.exists %}
```

OR

```
{% if notifications_approved.all or notifications_pending.all %}
```

You can use empty tag as well to check if empty:

```
{% for na in notifications_approved %}
    # code
{% empty %}
    # code for empty query set
{% endfor %}
```